# Handling auth token expiration in apollo client NextJS13

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, next.js13, react-apollo

I'm trying to handle the expiration of auth token in GraphQL, Apollo client in NextJS 13 application. This is the code I've written for the client provider,

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  HttpLink,
  ApolloLink,
  concat,
} from "@apollo/client";

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANDBOX_URL });

const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: localStorage.getItem("AuthToken") || null,
    },
  }));
  return forward(operation);
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

const ApolloClientProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>;
};

export default ApolloClientProvider;
```

Since I'm new to apollo client I want to write some custom function when the auth token expires. I couldn't able to find any best way to handle it. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the apollo-link-error package to handle network and GraphQL errors.

Sample:

```
const errorLink = onError(({ networkError }) => {
  if (networkError && networkError.statusCode === 401) {
    // Handle token expiration here. 401 (Unauthorized) 
    //checks for a 401 status, and then performs a token refresh 
  }
});

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([authMiddleware, errorLink, httpLink]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```